# when binding two .on "click" functions, one overwrites the other

Tags: jquery

These two links, when clicked:

```
 <a href="/modals.cfm?action=record_payment&amp;script=%2Fmanager%5Fpro%2Ecfm%2Fleague%2F268%2Faction%2Fregistration%2Fcontent%5Faction%2Fmanagedues%2Ftabindex%2F3&amp;player_id=41363&amp;dues_id=199&amp;league=268&amp;f_division_id=1014&amp;price2pay=10" class="btn btn-mini facebox ttLT btn-success" alt="Record Manual Payment for ashley wilkes" data-hasqtip="329" oldtitle="">Record Payment</a>

<a href="/manager_pro.cfm/league/268/action/registration/content_action/managedues/tabindex/3/m0dal_update/manageleague/submethod/manageusersdrop_members/player_id/40454" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to drop this member?">Drop Player</a>
```

trigger these functions:

```
    $(document).on("click", "a[data-confirm]", function(event){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
        $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">Please Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-warning" id="dataConfirmOK">I wish to continue</a></div></div>');
    } 
    $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
    $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
    $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
    event.preventDefault();
}); 

$(document).on("click", ".facebox", function(event){
    var $link = $(this);
    if ($(".modal").dialog( "isOpen" )===true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        new BootstrapDialog({
            title   :   '<h3>' + $link.attr('alt') + '</h3>',
            content :   $('<div>Loading...</div>').load($link.attr('href')),
            buttons :   [
                {
                    label   :   'Cancel',
                    onclick :   function(dialog){dialog.close();}
                }
            ]
        }).open();      
        event.preventDefault();
    }       
});
```

Each of them work individually but as soon as I click one, the other opens up the link to the full screen. Its as if one is overwriting or negating the binding of the other.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: that error along with the explanation your are giving doesn't quite match. if that's the error you're getting, neither of them should work individually or together.

Comment: yeah youre right, that error occurred after the link opened, it didnt cause the link to open. i removed it fromthis question.

Comment: @JeffShain if the answers are helping you mark them as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to move your `preventDefault` to the beginning of the handler function.

This works fine:

[FIDDLE ME](http://jsfiddle.net/9Tm4s/)